# How do I convert a question to a community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I asked 2 questions which in hindsight probbaly should be community wikis

However, when I select edit, I dont get the option to convert to community wiki. Any idea why?

[Dealing with women (or opposite gender?) when they quote "Medical issues"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/26007/dealing-with-women-or-opposite-gender-when-they-quote-medical-issues)

[How do you avoid interviewing for the company you work for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/how-do-you-avoid-interviewing-for-the-company-you-work-for)

Should they be CW? if so, how do I go and make the change? (I seem to remember being able to do it a while ago on another SE site, but I might be wrong)

Comment: In short: _Only_ the diamond mods can convert a question to cw. It is so since years.

Comment: Why do you think they should be community wiki?  What would the benefit to the commuity be if it were converted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the reason you can't, but note that both of those questions have answers.  Community Wiki on a question affects all answers too (from that point forward), so it makes sense to me that the asker of a question shouldn't be able to force that change on answerers unilaterally.  Making this change shifts the functional "ownership" of a post away from its author and also denies further reputation changes, which really only makes sense if a bunch of people are going to be sharing in the writing/editing of a post.

Community wiki is best used from the start, to allow the community to assemble a single canonical answer to a question.  Its benefit is less clear to me when a question already has a bunch of answers.  Community wiki is pretty rare, and Stack Exchange has been discouraging it for the last few years.

That said, moderators can convert a question (and thus its answers) to community wiki.  We would want to see clear consensus from the community on any specific proposal first.  For these two, I suggest you add one answer for each explaining why that question should be CW, so the community can vote on your proposal.  For future cases, just ask a new question, like people do when proposing that something be closed or reopened.

Comment: Thanks...  I guess I can leave making it a community wiki.. I was under the misconception that CW is also appropriate to posts with multiple correct answers

Comment: @user87166 that happens automatically if there are many, many answers. It's totally ok to have your questions keep giving you reputation - asking a good question is great!  SE's mechanism for that is probably bounties, you can offer reputation for great answers if you want (but this is not required at all).